# How to use {% pageurl %} from base.html

Tags: wagtail

I've got 3 Models: `BlogPage, PostPage, AboutPage`. I've created an instance of `AboutPage` with slug "about-page-slug". In my main folder I have base.html file. In this file I have created a navbar. This navbar has 3 links: BlogIndex, Posts and About. Now I want  "About" link from the navbar to navigate to "AboutPage" model instance that I've created before. I figured out that I can use `<a href="{% slugurl 'about-page-slug' %}"` to navigate to AboutPage model instance. But I can't figure out how I can use {% pageurl %} in base.html: to use it I need to provide an instance of the "AboutPage" model to the template 'base.html' but I don't have model to rewrite get_context_data() for it. So my question is: in case like this is the best way out to work with {% slugurl %} or there are some other ways to work it out with {% pageurl %}. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `{% slugurl %}`, or even simpler, hard-code `<a href="/about/">`, because surely your About page is never going to live at any other URL.

There are other possible approaches, such as calling `AboutPage.objects.first()` within a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) or a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) and passing the result to `{% pageurl %}`. But, frankly, the only reason *not* to hardcode the URL is if you're worried that someone might log in to the admin and carelessly (or maliciously) move or rename the page. (And if that's a scenario you think is worth defending against, presumably you *also* need to consider what happens if they delete the page entirely...)